# Loading images takes my direct memory up | AS3

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, memory, flashdevelop

I'm only loading bitmaps, without even adding them to the stage, each image takes my direct memory up. Large images will take even more memory, so I'm wondering how to keep direct memory low even after loading those bitmaps, or maybe I'm doing here something wrong or missing something?

```
    var myBitmapHolder:Bitmap; 

    var bitmapLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    bitmapLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bitmapLoaded);
    bitmapLoader.load(new URLRequest("myBitmap.png");

    private function bitmapLoaded(e:Event):void {
        myBitmapHolder = e.currentTarget.content;
    }
```

After loading the bitmap, I'm storing it using myBitmapHolder to access it upon request. I'm using more than 30 bitmaps, works the same as the example above for each image separately.

Comment: What do you think are those bitmaps loaded into? They are loaded into memory.

Comment: Where else are they supposed to go? If you want to keep your memory usage low, you should only load the images when needed.

Comment: If such a small app as mine takes a lot of memory only after loading few bitmaps, how could a big app handle, let's say more than 300 bitmaps? I posted my question because I'm not sure the way I handle loading bitmaps is the best way doing so.

Comment: Like I said, only load images when necessary is one possible approach. Do you need those 300 bitmaps over the entire runtime of the application?

Comment: If you are using more than one bitmap with identical content, you should hold the link to a `BitmapData` object and create new `Bitmap` objects while supplying a link to that bitmapdata in the constructor. And about many bitmaps, yes, apps do eat up memory on bitmaps, and quite a lot of it.

Comment: @DodgerThud, I can't know for sure because it's depends on user actions. I don't want to load it only when needed and removing it right after because it may force me loading the same bitmap again and again, which will take my memory even higher.

Comment: memory management is the coder task. If you don't need a bitmap or don't need it anytime soon it shouldn't be in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so ... there is no free resource - you have to load all in the memory, or you have to load then unload each or few bitmaps. That will 'eat' some other resource like cpu and network traffic etc.
First you have to remove 'bitmapLoader' Event.COMPLETE listener in 'bitmapLoaded' function: `bitmapLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, bitmapLoaded); }` 
 You have to be sure that you load the bitmap/s once. 
 Look at this: [AS3 - Memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034522/as3-memory-management) and [What are good memory management techniques in Flash/as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597003/what-are-good-memory-management-techniques-in-flash-as3).
 You can look at : [imageDecodingPolicy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#imageDecodingPolicy) also.